# Selenium Testing of Primary and Secondary sorting with a date

Tags: java, sorting, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a Selenium test to validate primary and secondary sorting within a table. My table includes a Name and Date/Time column. I need to verify that the date/time column is sorted in descending order and then by Name in ascending order. My code below works except for if the date is the same with a different time. How do I get it to factor in the time? For reference, I'm using Selenium 4.11.0 and Java 11.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
public void primaryAndSecondarySorting(List<String> col1, List<String> col2, int sortType){
List<String> concat = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < col1.size(); i++){
    concat.add(col1.get(i).concat("|").concat(col2.get(i)));
}       

List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>(concat);
Collections.sort(expected, sortType == 1 ? Collections.reverseOrder(String::compareTo) : String::compareTo);
assertTrue(concat.equals(expected));
```

}

Output:

concat{08/03/2023 2:31 PM|ABI, JOXXX, 06/13/2023 1:22 PM|BEE, STXXX, 06/06/2023 10:07 AM|AAXX, JEXXX, 06/06/2023 9:36 AM|BEE, FRXXX}

expected{08/03/2023 2:31 PM|ABI, JOXXX, 06/13/2023 1:22 PM|BEE, STXXX, 06/06/2023 9:36 AM|BEE, FRXXX, 06/06/2023 10:07 AM|AAXX, JEXXX}